# transferring SQL Server logins (windows authentication)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We are migrating our database from one server to another. we user the [script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992) provided by Microsoft. The script generates CREATE LOGIN statements with SID for SQL logins and it's successful in this bit. however, it didn't generate SID for windows authentication logins. I understand that those login used windows SID instead. is there anyway to transfer those logins and preserving SIDs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of orphan users on the new server this is not a problem with windows authenticated logins. There should be no problem to just copy them over as the sid is what ties the login to the sql login user but not in the case of windows authenticated ones.

If there are other reasons for wanting to transfer the sid for auth users this might not be right but I don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need.  The "FROM WINDOWS" clause in the script tells SQL Server to ask the OS for the SID.  As long as the new server is in the same domain as the old, it'll get the right SIDs from OS / AD.  If the new server is in a different domain, the SIDs will be different and you then have to resolve...see KB 240872 for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transfer Logins task in SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services)